# Force a domain controller to re-register AD DNS records without restarting netlogon?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

In the past, I've been in a situation troubleshooting the dynamic registration of AD specific DNS records from domain controllers against a 3rd party DNS server. As far as I'm aware, the netlogon service is responsible for these registrations and does a full pass each time it is started and on some regular interval (once an hour?).

So if I don't want to wait for the regular interval and I'd rather not restart the netlogon service (or reboot the DC), is there any other way to coerce netlogon into re-registering these records?

`ipconfig /registerdns` works for the DC's own A/PTR records. But I need a similar method for the rest of the AD SRV/A/CNAME records.

The closest thing I found in my web searching was [this blog post](https://www.serverbrain.org/domains-2003/refreshing-dns-resource-records-registration-fix.html) which talks about `netdiag /fix`. But apparently the netdiag utility no longer exists and the post implies that it would only re-register things that are missing. I've also tried various combinations of `dcdiag /fix` with no luck.

Comment: It's refreshing to see a question from someone who's experience/skills I respect about something that's never occurred to me. I don't have an answer but I'm looking forward to finding out if it's possible.

Comment: Cheers, Joe! Likewise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, `ipconfig /registerdns` only registers the main A and PTR records for a server; `netdiag` is obsolete and `dcdiag` only tests whether the proper DNS records are correctly registered, it doesn't actually fix them if they are not.

You can use `nltest /DSREGDNS` for this purpose; it should be available on any computer, even client ones; if running it from a non-DC computer, you can specify the DC you want to run it against using the `/SERVER:<servername>` parameter.

The quickest and simplest way is anyway to just restart the `netlogon` service on the DC that needs re-registering its DNS records.

Comment: Massimo, you're amazing! This is *exactly* what I was looking for. How did I never notice that flag before? Is it new'ish or has it literally been there like forever?