# How to resolve "Unable to obtain DNS hostname of Active Directory domain controller with ntdsa object name...."

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns

It starts as a programming problem:

```
Domain.GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers
```

triggers an exception:

> Unable to obtain DNS hostname of Active Directory domain controller
> with ntdsa object name "CN=NTDS
> Settings,CN=SERVER002,CN=Servers,CN=Site01,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=TLD,DC=org".

Because ONE domain controller has a problem, no domain controllers are returned.

This then becomes a DNS problem, I believe.

What entry, anywhere can I modify (manually if needed) to be able to get the value into DNS, correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be the answer....
https://serverfault.com/questions/1067632/force-a-domain-controller-to-re-register-ad-dns-records-without-restarting-netlo

Am investigating if this resolves the resolution issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be twofold.

I ran nltest /DSREGDNS as suggested by: [Force a domain controller to re-register AD DNS records without restarting netlogon?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067632/force-a-domain-controller-to-re-register-ad-dns-records-without-restarting-netlo)

And then my call worked only on the problem DC.

Replication from that DC had chosen to replicate to a DC that only can take in data, not write it out (but not an RODC - something that's an issue with one of our regions staff.... working on it

After creating forced replication links from the problem DC to other DCs in the org, it was then happy.

Hoping this helps someone else with a solution, since there is not much out there for information on this error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most convenient exception. Try using the PDC emulator role owner. That should always be available.

**PdcRoleOwner**

Gets the DomainController object that holds the primary domain controller (PDC) for this domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: The code needs to crawl all the DC's to see if an object is on them or not (we have a VERY large domain - 325 DCs) to see if a replacement machine can be added with the same name, and where the hold up might be.

Comment: Try the FindAllDiscoverableDomainControllers() method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.findalldiscoverabledomaincontrollers?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#system-directoryservices-activedirectory-domain-findalldiscoverabledomaincontrollers

Comment: That returns 41 of my 235 DC's.  I'm guessing that it's still erroring, just silently and stopping.

Comment: I believe it may exclude spoke site DCs that omit registering some records.

Comment: Another option to try is to query any working DC for all domain controllers (UAC flags, for example). Get the dnshostname for each, then test the network connections for each. That would get past the PowerShell limitations.