# Domain SRV records in DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I am configuring an Active Directory domain in an air-gapped network on Windows Server 2016. I can ping my DC and I am in the same subnet, pulling DHCP from the router, while the DC IPv4 is static.

I created the domain "mydomain.local" and added an A record for "mydc" in DNS > MYDC > Forward Lookup Zones > mydomain.local in DNS which is hosted on the same server as the DC.

When I try to add my laptop "mylaptop" to the domain in "Computer Name/Domain Changes" > Member of: > Domain > mydomain.local, an error appears:

"An AD DC for the domain "mydomain.local" could not be contacted.
The details say

```
The error was : "DNS server failure."
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.local
Common causes:
The DNS servers used by this computer contain incorrect root hints
One or more of the following zones contains incorrect delegation:
   mydomain.local
   local
   . (the root zone)
```

Further research on the issue reveals that my SRV records are wrong. Underneath Forward Lookup Zone > mydomain.local I see _msdcs zone (empty and dimmed, delegated folder?) and _tcp (empty, but I tried adding _kerberos, _ldap, and _msdcs SRV records).

I do not know how to create the correct SRV records due to not being able to add anything to the _msdcs folder.

From my laptop, nslookup "mydc.mydomain.local" returns the correct IP.

Comment: Use the windows DNS. This place here requires you to "Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault." -and you break them by the dozen.

Comment: I am not sure what IT management practices I am breaking here, could you please clarify? Also, where did you find the guideline you are referring to? I read the Code of Conduct page and I didn't see any violations in my post.

Comment: MS recommends using the WIndows integrated DNS -> managemend practice.

Comment: `I do not know how to create the correct SRV records due to not being able to add anything to the _msdcs folder.` you shouldn't need to add the records. Domain controllers add and manage their own SRV records.

Comment: Domain controllers register their own records. This can be forced with: https://serverfault.com/questions/1067632/force-a-domain-controller-to-re-register-ad-dns-records-without-restarting-netlo

Comment: This is where going through a simple video walk through will save you a lot of time and wheel spinning.